# Advanced Filter include blanks

Tags: excel, filter, advanced-filter

When using a criterion on numbers, for example `"<=0"` in an `Advanced Filter`, how can I include `blanks` with the results (as I considered them "<=0" too) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another row to your filter criteria, and use `=` in the criteria field for which you wish to include blank values.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do "<=0" and "=" in one criterion? My criteria table is quite complicated with multiple lines etc

Comment: No. You need to use multiple rows to specify multiple criteria.

Comment: Wow ok, It's gonna make the work waay  harder than I expected!! If I knew the hustle Advanced Filter comes with, I would have never use it!!

Comment: You may find it easier to use Power Query (Get and Transform Data) instead

Comment: Thank you, I will explore this option. Another work around is to replace blanks  with '0'  before running the filter that way they will appear with "<=0"